# Python issue with reading and calculating data from excel file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, calculation

[I have attached a screenshot of the excel file I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zksvc.png)
I am trying to read this excel file which has all the states (column B), Counties (column C) and Population (column D). I want to calculate the population for each state.

I know that there are various ways we all can do it and there is certainly a way to do this in fewer lines of easily understandable code. I will appreciate that but I would also like to know how to do this the way I am thinking which is - to first find out unique state names and then loop through the sheet to add all the columns by state.

Here is my code:

```
x = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Population by Census Tract')
PopData = {}
StateData = []
i = 3
j = 0
k=""

#First value entered
StateData.append(sheet['B' + str(2)].value)

#Unique State Values calculated
for row in range(i, sheet.max_row + 1):
    if any(sheet['B' + str(row)].value in s for s in StateData):
        i=i+1
    else:
        StateData.append(sheet['B' + str(row)].value)
print(StateData)

#Each State's Population calculated
for s in StateData:
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet['B' + str(row)].value == StateData[s]:
            j = j + sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    PopData[StateData[s]] = j 
print(PopData)
```

#### I am getting this error:

```
if sheet['B' + str(row)].value == StateData[s]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Apparently, `sheet` is a list while you are treating it as a dictionary. Only dictionaries can get values throughout "string" keys. A list can only get values using integers! We can help you more if you post at least a part of the excel sheet.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I have attached a screenshot of the excel file I am working with.

Comment: Hello, add also the `import` section of the code to help understand which modules you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following:

```
for s in StateData:
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet['B' + str(row)].value == StateData[s]:
            j = j + sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    PopData[StateData[s]] = j
```

`s` is already an element of the `StateData` list. What you want to do is probably:

```
for s in StateData:
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet['B' + str(row)].value == s:
            j = j + sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    PopData[StateData[s]] = j
```

or

```
for i, s in enumerate(StateData):
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet['B' + str(row)].value == StateData[i]:
            j = j + sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    PopData[StateData[s]] = j
```

but the first alternative is more elegant and (maybe) slightly faster.

Comment: Thank you again. The first option gave me the same error but this time on line "  PopData[StateData[s]] = j ".                                                                   So I used this code below and it worked.                                                                                        for i, s in enumerate(StateData):
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet['B' + str(row)].value == s:
            j = j + sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    PopData[StateData[i]] = j